exception in register using local api
I worked on an e-commerce app that has register, and I had problem with the register:
problem in registering a customer:
I used a local API, and my code has 3 layers (data layer, logic layer with cubit, and presentation layer).
and then I make a a request to add data to the database, it adds data correctly, but in Flutter code, it gives me an exception, and the exception is "Exception: Failed to post customer data: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Map<String, String>>'" and I don't use int in my code ever.
my code :
customer_model.dart:
class CustomerModel {
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? handle;
  String? phoneNumber;
  String? password;
  String? gender;
  String? address;

  CustomerModel({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.handle,
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.password,
    required this.gender,
    required this.address,
  });

  

  factory CustomerModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CustomerModel(
      firstName: json['firstName'],
      lastName: json['lastName'],
      handle: json['handle'],
      phoneNumber: json['phoneNumber'],
      password: json['password'],
      gender: json['gender'],
      address: json['address'],
    );
  }
}

customer_service.dart:
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class CustomerService {
  Future<Map<String, String>> post({
    required String url,
    required Map<String, String> customerData,
  }) async {
    try {
      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(url),
        body: jsonEncode(customerData),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        },
      );
      return jsonDecode(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Failed to post customer data: $e');
    }
  }
}

customer_repository.dart
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/data/models/customer_model.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/data/service/customer_service.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/utils/helper/constants/api.dart';

class CustomerRepository {
  final CustomerService addCustomerService;

  CustomerRepository(this.addCustomerService);

  Future<CustomerModel> addCustomer(
      {required Map<String, String> customerData}) async {
    final responseData = await addCustomerService.post(
      url: RegisterApi.addCustomer,
      customerData: customerData,
    );
    print('resonse of repo $responseData');
    return CustomerModel.fromJson(responseData);
  }
}

customer_states.dart:
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/data/models/customer_model.dart';

abstract class CustomerStates {}

class CustomerInitial extends CustomerStates {}

class CustomerWaiting extends CustomerStates {}

class CustomerSuccess extends CustomerStates {
  final CustomerModel customerModel;

  CustomerSuccess({required this.customerModel});
}

class CustomerFailure extends CustomerStates {
  final String error;

  CustomerFailure(this.error);
}

customer_cubit.dart:
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/data/repository/customer_repository.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/logic/customer_state.dart';

class CustomerCubit extends Cubit<CustomerStates> {
  final CustomerRepository addCustomerRepository;

  CustomerCubit(this.addCustomerRepository) : super(CustomerInitial());

  Future<void> customerCubit(
      {required Map<String, String> customerData}) async {
    emit(CustomerWaiting());
    try {
      final result =
          await addCustomerRepository.addCustomer(customerData: customerData);
      print('response of cubit $result');
      emit(CustomerSuccess(customerModel: result));
    } catch (e) {
      print('exception of cubit ${e.toString()}');
      emit(CustomerFailure(e.toString()));
    }
  }
}

signup_for_customer.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/home/presentation/views/home.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/data/repository/customer_repository.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/data/service/customer_service.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/logic/customer_cubit.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/logic/customer_state.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/account_created/views/account_created.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/presentation/widgets/sign_up_form_for_customer.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/utils/components/leading_icon.dart';

class SignUpForCustomer extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignUpForCustomer({super.key});
  static String id = 'SignUpWithEmailForCustomer';

  @override
  State<SignUpForCustomer> createState() => _SignUpForCustomerState();
}

GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey();

class _SignUpForCustomerState extends State<SignUpForCustomer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => CustomerCubit(CustomerRepository(CustomerService())),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Sign Up'),
          leading: const LeadingIcon(),
        ),
        body: BlocConsumer<CustomerCubit, CustomerStates>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state is CustomerWaiting) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                const SnackBar(
                  content: Text('Loading...'),
                ),
              );
            } else if (state is CustomerSuccess) {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, AccountCreated.id);
            } else if (state is CustomerFailure) {
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(
                  content: Text(state.error),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            return SignUpFormforCustomer();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

gender_choice.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';

import '../../../../../../../utils/helper/constants/images.dart';
import '../../../supplier_or_customer/widges/sign_up_choice.dart';

class GenderChoice extends StatefulWidget {
  GenderChoice({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  String? gender;

  @override
  GenderChoiceState createState() => GenderChoiceState();
}

class GenderChoiceState extends State<GenderChoice> {
  bool isSelectMan = false;
  bool isSelectWoman = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        StoreOrCustomer(
          image: kBoyIcon,
          tap: () => setState(() {
            isSelectMan = true;
            isSelectWoman = false;
            widget.gender = "man";
          }),
          isSelect: isSelectMan,
          selectedRadius: 50,
          selectedRadiusColor: 52,
          unSelectedRadius: 50,
        ),
        const Gap(45),
        StoreOrCustomer(
          image: kGirlIcon,
          tap: () => setState(() {
            isSelectMan = false;
            isSelectWoman = true;
            widget.gender = "woman";
          }),
          isSelect: isSelectWoman,
          selectedRadius: 50,
          selectedRadiusColor: 52,
          unSelectedRadius: 50,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

signup_form_textfield.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/login/presentation/widgets/forget_password/phone_verification_textfield.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/presentation/widgets/gender_choice.dart';

import '../../../../../../../utils/components/text_form_field.dart';
import '../../../../../../../utils/helper/functions/regex.dart';

class SignupTextFieldForCustomer extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignupTextFieldForCustomer({
    super.key,
    required this.formKey,
    required this.firstNameController,
    required this.lastNameController,
    // required this.phoneController,
    required this.passwordController,
    required this.emailController,

    // required this.password,
    // required this.username,
    // required this.firstName,
    // required this.lastName,
    // required this.phone
  });
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey;
  // String? password, username, firstName, lastName, phone;
  final TextEditingController firstNameController;
  final TextEditingController lastNameController;
  // final TextEditingController phoneController;
  final TextEditingController passwordController;
  final TextEditingController emailController;

  @override
  State<SignupTextFieldForCustomer> createState() =>
      _SignupTextFieldForCustomerState();
}

const bool hide = false;

class _SignupTextFieldForCustomerState
    extends State<SignupTextFieldForCustomer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: widget.formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              //first name
              TextFormFieldWidget(
                controller: widget.firstNameController,
                width: 150,
                paaddingRight: 0,
                paddingLeft: 30,
                paddingbottom: 0,
                paddingTop: 0,
                labelText: 'First Name',
                keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                validate: (value) {
                  if (value!.isNotEmpty) {
                    if (!value.contains(firstNameRegExp)) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid first name';
                    }
                  } else if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'This field is empty!!!';
                  }
                  // widget.firstName = value;

                  return null;
                },
              ),
              //last name
              TextFormFieldWidget(
                controller: widget.lastNameController,
                width: 150,
                paddingLeft: 46,
                paddingTop: 0,
                paddingbottom: 0,
                labelText: 'Last Name',
                keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                validate: (value) {
                  if (value!.isNotEmpty) {
                    if (!value.contains(lastNameRegExp)) {
                      return 'Please enter a valid last name';
                    }
                  } else if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'This field is empty!!!';
                  }
                  // widget.lastName = value;
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),

          //email
          TextFormFieldWidget(
            controller: widget.emailController,
            paddingbottom: 0,
            paddingTop: 0,
            labelText: 'Email',
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            validate: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return 'Email is required';
              } else if (value.toLowerCase().isNotEmpty) {
                if (!value.contains(emailRegExp)) {
                  return 'Please enter a valid email address';
                }
              }
              // widget.email = value;
              return null;
            },
          ),

          // phone number
          // PhoneVerificationTextField(
          //   phoneNumber: '01211212239',
          //   lengthCheck: true,
          //   controller: widget.phoneController,
          // ),

          //password
          TextFormFieldWidget(
            paddingbottom: 0,
            paddingTop: 0,
            controller: widget.passwordController,
            labelText: 'password',
            obscure: hide,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            validate: (value) {
              // widget.password = value;
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return 'password is required';
              } else if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                if (!value.contains(passwordRegExp)) {
                  return 'Password must be at least contain \n1. One small character \n2. One capital character \n3. One special character \n4. One number';
                }
              }
              // widget.password = value;
              return null;
            },
          ),

          //confirm password
          TextFormFieldWidget(
            paddingTop: 0,
            paddingbottom: 0,
            labelText: 'Confirm password',
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            obscure: hide,
            validate: (value) {
              if (value != widget.passwordController.text || value!.isEmpty) {
                return 'Password and Confirm Password must be same';
              }

              return null;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

signup_form_field.dart:
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/custom_widgets/signup_alert_dialog.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/logic/customer_cubit.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/custom_widgets/already_have_account.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/custom_widgets/confirm_policy.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/presentation/widgets/gender_choice.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/modules/register/signup/modules/customer/presentation/widgets/signup_textfield_for_customer.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/utils/components/button.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/utils/helper/constants/colors.dart';
import 'package:on_budget/src/utils/components/background.dart';

class SignUpFormforCustomer extends StatelessWidget {
  SignUpFormforCustomer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  // Create a single instance of GenderChoice with a GlobalKey
  final GlobalKey<GenderChoiceState> genderChoiceKey =
      GlobalKey<GenderChoiceState>();
  final GlobalKey<ConfirmPolicyState> confirmPolicykey =
      GlobalKey<ConfirmPolicyState>();

  bool genderIsSelected = false;
  bool isValid = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Background(
      child: ListView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              const Gap(20),
              GenderChoice(key: genderChoiceKey), // Use the key here
              const Gap(20),
              SignupTextFieldForCustomer(
                formKey: formKey,
                firstNameController: firstNameController,
                lastNameController: lastNameController,
                // phoneController: phoneController,
                passwordController: passwordController,
                emailController: emailController,
              ),
              const Gap(20),
              ConfirmPolicy(
                key: confirmPolicykey,
              ),
              const Gap(30),
              Button(
                text: 'Sign Up',
                tap: () {
                  if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    formKey.currentState!.save();
                    isValid = true;
                  }
                  if (isValid) {
                    final cubit = context.read<CustomerCubit>();
                    final genderState = genderChoiceKey.currentState;
                    final isGenderSelected = genderState?.widget.gender;
                    final isConfirmPolicySelected =
                        confirmPolicykey.currentState?.checkBox ?? false;
                    if (isGenderSelected == null) {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return const SignUpAlertDialog(
                            text: 'Please choose your gender type',
                            button: 'Okaaay',
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (isConfirmPolicySelected == false) {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (context) {
                          return const SignUpAlertDialog(
                            text: 'Accept to our Terms and Policies',
                            button: 'Okaaay',
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (isGenderSelected == 'man' ||
                        isGenderSelected == 'woman' ||
                        isConfirmPolicySelected == true ||
                        isValid == true) {
                      log('$isValid');
                      cubit.customerCubit(customerData: {
                        "firstName": firstNameController.text,
                        "lastName": lastNameController.text,
                        "handle": emailController.text,
                        "gender": isGenderSelected,
                        "phoneNumber": '',
                        "address": '',
                        "password": passwordController.text
                      });
                    }
                  }
                },
                width: 220,
                colorBtn: kPrimaryColor,
                colorTxt: kSecondaryColor,
                height: 30,
                textSize: 20,
              ),
              const Gap(20),
              const AlreadyHaveAccount(),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Check what the 'response.body' is in 'customer_service.dart' > 'post' function as it may not be returning the expected type

it returns an integer value and the value is 4 but why?

Additional Information: When I make a log-in status code in the service, give me (201) and when I make a log in response.body  It gives me 10, and the 10 is the ID of the customer that registered in the database

It seems like your API is returning the wrong data
